# OPENJPA FetchType

Tags: jpa, openjpa

What is the default fetch type for OPENJPA? I know for Hibernate it is LAZY. By default I am assuming that when you declare a particular nested field, you do not specify the fetch type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA is a spec for persistence. It defines what is the default (I'd recommend a glance at it). For 1-1/N-1 is EAGER, and for 1-N/M-N is LAZY. All JPA implementations should follow this *to be compliant*

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason why 1-1/N-1 is EAGER? I thought for better performance, it should always be LAZY by default

Comment: Best ask the people on the JPA EG, but from a simple RDBMS point of view a 1-1 relation can be fetched in the same call as any basic field hence is more efficient to do then; doesn't mean that the JPA implementation will do a join to get all fields of the related object, just the FK column as a minimum